# max-age, no-Cache,must-revalidate on Cache-Control Header, Which takes predence here?

Tags: http, caching, http-headers, response-headers

Cache-Control : max-age=86400, no-store, must-revalidate, no-cache

This is a response header set by the server for a JS file.

Does it mean the response is cached for 86400 seconds before revalidating?.

Which of the above one takes precedence and what is the resiult?.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like no-cache is give precedence over all. 
HTTP1.1 specification says "`If the no-cache directive does not specify a field-name, then a cache MUST NOT use the response to satisfy a subsequent request without successful revalidation with the origin server.`" 
Refer http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.9.1

It also says "`The max-age directive on a response implies that the response is cacheable (i.e., "public") unless some other, more restrictive cache directive is also present.` "
Refer http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.9.3

All the above are for HTTP/1.1 .